# Git automerge does not show the expected conflicts

Tags: git

I have a forked a repo, I would like to periodically merged with the original repo. In case there are changes at same line in both forked as well as original repo, then git automerge discards the changes in original repo, and takes changes from my repo as final.

Does not even show up as conflict

Repo1 : Starting point(Team A)
Repo2 : Fork of Repo1(Team B)

In Test.java the original code at line 28 was

Apple = 11;

Team B makes changes to Repo2(ex Test.java).
Adds other enums at line 28

```
{
Apple = 11;
Orange = 12;
Banana = 13;
Peach = 14;
}
```

Meanwhile in Repo1 Team A has added

```
{
Apple = 11;
Grapes= 12;
Watermelon= 13;
}
```

I have setup Repo1 as remote for Repo2

Following commands
Repo2# : git remote add repo1master https://github.....
Repo2# : git fetch repo1master 
Repo2#: git merge repo1master/master

We would expect git would give a conflict at above lines.. but it does not. It discards changes in Repo1 at that location and takes only Repo2.
Output of automerge is this and no conflicts for this. We would never notice it by doing automerge

```
{
Apple = 11;
Orange = 12;
Banana = 13;
Peach = 14;
}
```

How do I make sure git throws up conflicts at these and similar conflicting lines.

Comment: This is not how git should be behaving - can you reproduce this problem?